# Javafx -- are ReadOnlyDoubleWrappers ever garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javafx

If you read the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper.java#ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper) for `ReadOnyObjectWrapper`, you will see that the `getReadOnlyProperty()` method uses a simple singleton instance scheme, i.e.

```
ReadOnlyPropertyImp readOnlyProperty;

public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty getReadOnlyProperty(){
    if(readOnlyProperty == null){
        readOnlyProperty = new ReadOnlyPropertyImp();
    }
    return readOnlyProperty;
}
```

where `ReadOnlyPropertyImp` is a nested class extending `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty`. It seems to me, though, that if I were to do

```
ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper wrapper= new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
ReadOnlyDoubleProperty property = wrapper.getReadOnlyProperty();
```

now neither `wrapper` nor `property` will ever be garbage-collected since each contains a strong reference to the other. Is this accurate?

Comment: If all references to wrapper AND property are lost, they will both be garbage collected. It doesn't matter that they reference each other. If nothing references either of them, then no live objects can reach them, and they get gc'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, if all references to both objects go out of scope, the values will be GC'ed. Check out this code:

```
public class Main
{
static WeakReference<StrongReference> wr1;
static WeakReference<StrongReference> wr2;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main m = new Main();

    System.out.println(wr1.get() == null);
    System.out.println(wr2.get() == null);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 5) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //attempt to invoke GC
        System.out.println("GC Hint");
        System.gc();
        count ++;
    }

    System.out.println(wr1.get() == null);
    System.out.println(wr2.get() == null);
}

public Main() {
    wr1 = new WeakReference<StrongReference>( new StrongReference());
    wr2 = new WeakReference<StrongReference>( new StrongReference());
    wr1.get().setRef(wr2.get());
    wr2.get().setRef(wr1.get());

    System.out.println("SR 1 references - " + wr1.get().getRef().toString());
    System.out.println("SR 2 references - " + wr2.get().getRef().toString());
}


private class StrongReference {
    private Object myRef;

    public void setRef(Object o) {
        myRef = o;
    }

    public Object getRef() { 
        return myRef;
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
SR 1 references - com.so.test.Main$StrongReference@c21495
SR 2 references - com.so.test.Main$StrongReference@1d5550d
false
false
GC Hint
GC Hint
GC Hint
GC Hint
GC Hint
true
true
```

In this code, I have two objects of StrongReference type, which reference eachother. You would think they could never be GC'ed, but they can be. I wrap them in a WeakReference object to break the chain of references to them after they are created, and allow GC to get its hands on them. Even though they reference eachother, the values will still return null from the WeakReference call to get() because GC has cleared them. I should note that is is possible that GC doesnt run during that 5 second loop. Im simply providing a hint to the JVM to perform GC, not actually invoking, so results may vary